# Unable to rewrite user friendly URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a URL called `example.com/profiles/?id=(Any id/number that has a profile)`. I want to change this URL to a user friendly URL like so:

```
example.com/profiles/2
```

I've tried rewriting `.htaccess` like so:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/profiles/username/([\d]+)$ profiles.php?id=$1
```

I've also tried this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/profiles/([0-9]+)\.html /profiles/?id=$1
```

Both of these methods failed. I already have a rewrite rule where file extensions are terminated. I don't understand why my friendly URL is not working.

Comment: RewriteRule ^/profiles/([0-9]+) /profiles/?id=$1

Comment: @Farkie That still wouldn't work in `.htaccess` because of the slash prefix on the URL-path.

Answer (score 3):

In both cases, you don't match the desired pattern. The first one has `username` in between, and the second rule matches only with a trailing `.html`. And the pattern doesn't include a leading slash `/`, when used in a directory (.htaccess) context, see [`RewriteRule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)

> **Per-directory Rewrites**
>   - ...
>   - The removed prefix always ends with a slash, meaning the matching occurs against a string which never has a leading slash. Therefore, a Pattern with ^/ never matches in per-directory context.

Furthermore, in the two rules, you rewrite to different targets.

To match what you have written `example.com/profiles/2` to `example.com/profiles/?id=2`, use

```
RewriteRule ^profiles/(\d+)$ /profiles/?id=$1 [L]
```

---

To redirect the other way round, you must first capture the `id` in a [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) with `QUERY_STRING` and then use it in a `RewriteRule`

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=(\d+)
RewriteRule ^profiles$ /profiles/%1 [R,L]
```

---

Now, when you use both rules together, you will get a redirect loop. To prevent this loop, insert at the beginning

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

Comment: For some reason it's still not working. My URL is example.com/profiles/?id=2, but it's not changing it to example.com/profiles/2

Comment: This rule is for rewriting from `/profiles/2` to `/profiles/?id=2`. To do both this rule and a redirect, see modified answer.

Comment: This is working, but when I go about entering /profiles/2, the page cannot be found. In my PHP code I have a GET statement, where it says $id = $_GET["id"];, how do I go about fixing this so the page can be displayed?

Comment: What is the name of your PHP script?

Comment: example.com/profiles/index.php is the name of the script. profiles is the folder, and inside is a index.php

Answer (score 0):

Simplest case of URL rewriting is to rename a single static Web page, and this is far easier than the B&Q example above. To use Apache’s URL rewriting function, you will need to create or edit the .htaccess file in your website’s document root (or, less commonly, in a subdirectory).

For instance, if you have a Web page about `mypage` named `Ab3d4JK.htm`, you could add these lines to .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule   mypage.htm   Ab3d4JK.htm
```

Now, if you visit , you’ll actually be shown the Web page `Ab3d4JK.htm`. Furthermore, your browser will remain at `mypage.htm`, so visitors and search engines will never know that you originally gave the page such a cryptic name. User friendly URLs are not only beneficial also helpful to boost your SEO. URL rewriting allows you to completely separate the URL from the resource.

Comment: StackOverflow is a Q&A site. When you write an answer on StackOverflow you need to (at some point) address the actual question. What you've provided here is just a bit of background as to what URL rewriting is, which the OP would already seem to be familiar with. You've not attempted to answer the specific problem posed in the question.